# Getting null pointer during acquiring Portal session in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, session, servlets, websphere, portal

I am using WebSphere Portal Server 8.0 and I am working on a multiuser application in which user can generate and download dynamic pdf and download pdf  code is in servlet. I am generating portal session and portal request (it extends http request) from java class (it is in Portlet project) then hitting the servlet. for single user it works fine for multi-user as well it works fine (if we have some delay between then user clicking the generate pdf button).

But when 2 different user click generate pdf (login as different users and from different machine) at the moment one user gets the session and generates the pdf but other user gets the null pointer exception with this stack trace:

My method is:

```
public final void setSessionParameter(parameter1,parameter2){
PortletRequest req= getPortletRequest() // getting portlet req
PortletSession session= req.getPortletSession(); 
// here for first user (for first request ) it gives proper session but for
   other request with it gives exception bcz of null session
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Hashtable.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTRequestContext.getSession(SRTRequestContext.java:77)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getSession(SRTServletRequest.java:1772)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getSession(SRTServletRequest.java:1759)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:248)
 at ilog.rules.webui.IlrWUtils.restoreLastEditedDate(IlrWUtils.java:182)
 at ilog.rules.webui.IlrWDateValueEditorActionManager.<init>(IlrWDateValueEditorActionManager.java:29)
 at ilog.rules.webui.IlrWFullDateEditor.<init>(IlrWFullDateEditor.java:23)
```

Comment: @basic This is an NPE in code not the user can't change code, so that "possible duplicate" is irrelevant.

Comment: Is your portlet project JSR286?  If so, why did you choose to have a servlet instead of using the serveResource of the portlet?

Comment: It's a old implementation .. and I have to solve this problem

Comment: Are you trying to get the session in the servlet or is this happening in the portlet?  Can you show the method you are using to get the portlet request?